# Drawing off screen using XNA SpriteBatch

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I have a `SpriteBatch` that is set to draw to a `RenderTarget2D` that is 500px larger in both height and width. However, whenever I call the `SpriteBatch.Draw` method using a point outside of the physical screen width/height it will not draw the object.

I am performing some 3D transforms on the texture so I need the areas outside the screen to be drawn. I have tried setting culling to `None` and this had no effect.

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Viewport to match the render target size?

Comment: This question was cross-posted to GDSE: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15993/xna-spritebatch-drawing-off-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `Viewport` on your `GraphicsDevice` before drawing to your `RenderTarget2D`.

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(myRenderTarget2D);
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width += 500; //or a more sensible calculation
GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height += 500;
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
//Spritebatch operations
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.viewport

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport_members